# recursive inequality

Tags: calculus

Let $\alpha(1), \cdots , \alpha(n), \cdots $ be a strictly incrising sequence of natural numbers such that $\alpha(1) = 1$, $\alpha(2)=3$, and for each $n\geq 3$ it satisfies in the following inequality:

$$\alpha (n)\leq \alpha\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right) + \alpha\left(\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil -1\right)+n$$

Find a "good" upper bound for $\alpha(n)$ in terms of $n$. Actually, I have already found this upper bound, $n\times\lfloor{\log_2 n}\rfloor+2$. I am asking about improvement this bound.